# How best to search a key with partial matches that may be out of order

Tags: php, sql, search

I am working on a database with food items. An example item may be "Almond Joy Non-Dairy Coffee Creamer". I would like a user to be able to search "Almond Joy" and see this as a result, but also see it when they type "Almond" or even "Non-Dairy" or "Coffee Creamer". Furthermore, I would like a user to be able to search "Coffee Creamer Non-Dairy" or "Coffee Creamer Almond Joy" and see the result.

Basically, I would like a fast algorithm that gets partial string matches among a full string. I am not entirely sure what method would be the quickest. We are using PHP and SQL database. The database is pretty massive, consisting of all the foods sold in America.

Edit 1: I was informed by my coworker that we really only need this search to be performed on a list of foods like a text file. The format is very basic, and would look like:

```
0.33 lb bacon & cheddar patties
03 grape fruit drinking vinegar
03 grape fruit drinking vinegar
04 fruit punch smart energy drink, 04 fruit punch
```

Basically the PHP reads the text file, and as the user inputs text we would search through this file (really an array of each line as a string) and bring up matches as they appear to  the HTML. When a user is satisfied with a match, that is when we would actually query the SQL.

Comment: We need to see the model, and the controller code to give relevant code.

Comment: I don't wanna propose a vague solution for partial querying that gets downvoted :)

Comment: Be clear. You want this with PHP or SQL query?

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the post. It is actually more like just searching through a list of items in general for matches. Language would be PHP.

Comment: @Steak Makes sense. Are you aware of Trie data structure?

Comment: @nice_dev I was not. This does look very promising. Looking at this link (https://www.studytonight.com/advanced-data-structures/trie-data-structure-explained-with-examples) it appears that we could do full match and starts with searches. Of course I will look further into it, but would this also allow partial searches and unordered matches?

Comment: @Steak Yes. I can demonstrate via code but only if you wish to adapt this approach.

Comment: @nice_dev At the moment this seems very appealing. If possible, I would love to see it if you have the time. Thank you.

Comment: @Steak Sounds great. I will let you know.

Comment: @Steak You can try [`this snippet`](https://pastebin.com/2fvpMSKB) with this [`text file`](https://pastebin.com/pX4vdrtS);

Comment: Did it help?......

Comment: @nice_dev Yes, this was very helpful. I have been trying to fix a couple of things however; for instance with an empty string the trie returns (given the 4 items listed in the post) 0.33 lb bacon & cheddar patties, and furthermore I would like it to match prefixes as well. I'm looking into prefix tries now as well.

Comment: @Steak The issue was with a punctuation symbol. Fixed it [`here`](https://pastebin.com/h1grhwSD). If you want prefix search too, you can include searching word by word with the help of [`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php)

Comment: @nice_dev Great, thank you. In the end a trie takes up too much memory and cannot be easily stored so we are looking at alternatives. However, I do appreciate the effort you put into these comments!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to go for [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Read up on this, it will help your use case. For the kind of solution that you are looking for, you need to think beyond the regularly-used capabilities of a database, like trying different `LIKE` clauses, for example. Instead look for more specialized solutions that meet your requirement, especially since it looks like you need something that can scale.